# PDF Toggle different values in auto populated fields while not affecting original input

Tags: javascript, pdf, code-formatting, acrobat

I am working on a pdf file with many pages with a persons' name on eacb page. I named the label the same thing in all the fields to easily automate the name throughout the pdf.

The client wants functionality to change the name throughout the document, so now when I try to change the name on a page besides the first (When it asks your  name initially) it changes all fields, for example:

[image: Table of what I need accomplished]

I was thinking of running simple javascript in each field:

```
this.getField("Date") = event.value || event.value = event.value;
```

I got to thinking of the scope of the script. I am working in the actions tab in  the property so do I really need to set variables? So I did:

var name000 = this.getField("Name");
name000 == event.value || event.value == event.value;

Then I went through the entire document and uniquely changed all the field names. Instead of Date for all, Name00, Name01, Name02, Name03, etc, all the way to Name24.

Used for the first few labels:

```
this.getField("Date").value = this.getField("Date00").value;
this.getField("Date").value = this.getField("Date01").value;
this.getField("Date").value = this.getField("Date02").value;
```

The problem with this scenario is after Date00 the fields are empty like I haven't done anything. Added variable as so, same situation

```
this.getField("Name") = event;
// set value of field "Name" to this field's value;
this.getField("Name00").value = event.value;
// end on blur action for field Date;


var Name1 = this.getField("Name");
var Name2 = this.getField("Name01");
Name2.value = Name1.value;
// end on blur action for field Date;

var Name1 = this.getField("Name");
var Name3 = this.getField("Name02");
Name3.value = Name1.value;

Third label is blank, so I assigned unique variables named the Name Field differently and still blank after I assign more than one field.

var name000 = this.getField("Date");
name000 == event.value || event.value == event.value; <-- This has the same problem.
```

9/2 update.

this.getField("Name") = event.value || event.value = event.value; Onblur Javascript errors "SyntaxError: Invalid assignment on left-hand side." Just from this error alone I don't want to go through the entire form to correct all Field names "Name". I have them named differently:
Name, Name01, Name02, 03,10, until Name24

Plus it seems time consuming togo to every field copying:

```
this.getField("Name") = event.value || event.value = event.value;
this.getField("Name00") = event.value || event.value = event.value;
this.getField("Name01") = event.value || event.value = event.value;
this.getField("Name02") = event.value || event.value = event.value;
this.getField("Name03") = event.value || event.value = event.value;
           " \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"
this.getField("Name24") = event.value || event.value = event.value;
```

it doesn't compute anyways.

Tries an OOP script for more automation and less code:

```
var i f fi nv;
function n(f){
    return n > 9 ? "" + n: "0" + n;
}

f = this.getField(“Name") = event.value;

fi = this.getField("'Name' + i") = event.value;

nv = event.value = event.value;

while (i = 0; i < i++) {
return i <= 24;
};

f fi || nv;
```

I get an error though, missing ';' at line 2?

From the blog I noticed they used one script for only the first field to complete the task. Can I change the update all same fields through the PDF main Javascript meta data? Has anyone done this?
Is there a simple way or anyway to solve this? I have spent way too much time on this.

Comment: I have been working on this challenge I can not figure it out. I found this blog posting that has an example from previous versions of Acrobat X, but the Javascript logic is there.-->https://blogs.uoregon.edu/developments/2010/07/14/use-data-from-one-field-to-populate-other-fields-in-an-acrobat-fill-in-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation I discovered that each field needs to be unique, every field except the primary needs JavaScript to run OnBlur in the actions tab in the fields' property:

```
//Set the source and destination vars:
      var source = this.getField("ClientName");
      var destination = this.getField("CN2");

//See if destination is empty and if so, insert source value
      if(destination.value==''||destination.value==null){destination.value=source.value}
```